# What is the difference between " and ' in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

When should I use "? And when should I use ' in PostgreSQL?

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL,
  first_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ;



INSERT INTO "user" (id, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES
(1, 'website', 'admin', 'admin@example.com')
```

Why the values need to use ' , the table name should use " and columns don't have to use any quotation? I don't get it.

Comment: I found this as the first result when searching for "postgresql quotes": https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/postgresql/short-guides/quoting-rules. See if that answers your question.

Comment: Double quotes are used to enclose identifiers with special characters, while single quotes are used to enclose literal strings.

Comment: That's standard in SQL, not just in PostgreSQL. Check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, the double quotes are used to quote [Identifiers and Keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) that are otherwise illegal identifiers. `user` is a keyword and a built-in function. So you need to use double quotes to escape that. Quoted identifiers are case sensitive (as defined by the SQL standard). So `"user"` and `"User"` are two different names.

In general it's better to avoid identifiers that need quoting, thus you never have the need to use double quotes with your identifiers. You could e.g. use `user_account` instead of `user`.

Single quotes are used in SQL to enclose [string constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS)